# Unable to gain focus on JTextField used in JDialog for the second time on linux server

Tags: java, linux, swing, focus, jdialog

I am using a JDialog with 2 JTextfields and JButtons in it. When Jdialog opens for the first time I have a cursor on my first textfield. Now if I click somewhere outside Jdialog and then try clicking back the JDialog, I dont see the cursor on any of the textfields and I am unable to write or edit anything on the textfields.

I have set the modal to be true. So even If I click anywhere else my dialog still appears on the screen but gets deactivated.

This issue is only with linux server and not on windows. Windows works perfectly.

Adding a sample code here to get some picture of the issue.
Here TestClass is extending JFrame.

```
public TestClass(){
    setSize(new Dimension(600,500));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    myPanel = new JPanel();


    JButton openDialog = new JButton("Click here");
    openDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog = new JDialog(myFrame,true);
            dialog.setSize(new Dimension(400,400));

            JTextField myField = new JTextField(10);
            JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
            innerPanel.add(myField);

            dialog.add(innerPanel);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            //add(dialog);
        }
    });


    myPanel.add(openDialog);
    add(myPanel);
}
```

Comment: could be incorrect dialog's parent issue (null or wrong JFrame/JDialog)

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe; also specify versions.

Comment: hi where can I add my code? In the comments section?

Comment: which part of _edit your question_ don't you understand :-)

Comment: happens kleopatra.. struggling to solve this problem from a very long time. My mind is blocked :)

Comment: I see this/the same question here a few times, ended with decison to use JFrame instead of JDialog/JWindow

Comment: But can I set Modal for JFrame?

Comment: @user1815809 not there is no way, this is basic property of JDialog

Answer (score 1):

Your incomplete example could not be tested. The example below exhibits the expected behavior under Java 6 on both Mac OS X and Ubuntu 12. In particular, the text field remains functional after switching back from another program.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15576897/230513
 */
public class TestClass extends JFrame {

    private static JFrame myFrame;

    public TestClass() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JButton openDialog = new JButton("Click here");
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        myPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Click here") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JDialog dialog = new JDialog(myFrame, true);
                JTextField myField = new JTextField(10);
                JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
                innerPanel.add(myField);
                dialog.add(innerPanel);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setSize(new Dimension(160, 120));
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(myFrame);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }));
        add(myPanel);
        pack();
        setSize(new Dimension(320, 240));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myFrame = new TestClass();
            }
        });
    }
}
```